# How can I send mail to multiple users without the users knowing eachother's emails using PHP?

Tags: php, email

What I have is this:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM users";
            $query = mysql_query($SQL) OR die(mysql_error());
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
            $implodeEmail = implode(", ", $row['paypal']);
            $mailTo = "noreply@" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
            $mailSubject = $bootTitle;
            $mailMessage = $_POST['massemail'];
            $mailHeaders =  "From: noreply@" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "\r\n" .
                            "Reply-To: noreply@" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "\r\n" .
                            "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . "\r\n" .
                            "Bcc: " . $implodeEmail;
            if (mail($mailTo, $mailSubject, $mailMessage, $mailHeaders))
            {
                echo "e-Mail successfully sent.";
            }
```

It successfully sends to the $mailTo, but I want it to Bcc to everyone's paypal email, and that isn't working. I thought about just making all emails visible, but I really don't want that, and I don't want to loop through each one and send out an email for each person.

Ideas/help?

Comment: You could send separate email to each user :)

Comment: I thought about that, but wouldn't that make it look like my server was sending out SPAM?

Comment: You would only look like spam if you don't have proper headers and / or the users mark you as spam, which can happen on single emails as well. Just make sure the from address is actually the domain it was sent from. You can get more sophisticated as well, like making sure you don't send twice using mail queues, and don't kill the server by sending batches of like 200k at a time. At the firm I work for, we batch 100 at a time, make sure headers are clean and send from the domain. Our spam score is very low.

Comment: I would go the individual route, too. I think spam filters look at the content, origination and headers all as one. If you are sending legit emails, one at a time, to a lot of people I don't think it will be flagged as spam just because you are sending out a lot. Just make sure all of your MX records and machine names are set up correctly. I haven't had to do that in years but it pays off because your machine is seen as legit and not a rooted spambot server

Comment: FYI... @KaiQing posted while I was composing; it's good advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a rough idea:

```
$implodeEmail = implode("; ", $row['paypal']);
```

or just noticed that instead of:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$implodeEmail = implode(", ", $row['paypal']);
```

should be:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) $rows[]=$row['paypal'];
$implodeEmail = implode(", ", $rows);
```

Comment: Whoops, I should have noticed that. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 0):

If you include all the addresses in the Bcc header, the server should send a copy to each one. If he doesn't do that, something is wrong with the server. Look in the php.ini mail config, and test your mailserver. And yeah, you should use ";" instead of "," to implode the addresses.

Answer (score -1):

Try phpMailer or SwiftMailer.

Comment: Link : http://quomon.com/question-How-do-I-set-a-BCC-address-when-sending-email-in-PHP-428.aspx